# "Server Error" when users try to create a new account - Magento 1.7

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, internal-server-error

I'm setting up our Magento 1.7 store, hoping to be ready for launch soon. I've noticed a problem:

When users try to create a new account, they fill out their info on /customer/account/create page just fine, then when they click submit, they get this 500 Error:

> The website encountered an error while retrieving
>   http://example.com/customer/account/createpost/.

the account is actually created, however.

Similar deal on when users submit their email on the Forgot Password page, they press submit and get this:

> The website encountered an error while retrieving
>   http://example.com/customer/account/forgotpasswordpost/.

no email is sent.

If you see this and know how to help with this prob, your advice would be much appreciated, truly.

In case it helps, we are using a theme, rather than default.

---

**EDIT** - (I was asked if I had checked server error)
My server errors show as this, for the above situations:

Forgot Password submit shows this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mandrill_API::addTo() in
>   D:\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Email\Template.php on line
>   438

and

Create Account submit shows this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mandrill_API::addTo() in
>   D:\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Email\Template.php on line
>   438

as well.

Here is 6 lines(437-442) of that Template.php file:

```
foreach ($emails as $key => $email) {
            $mail->addTo($email, '=?utf-8?B?' . base64_encode($names[$key]) . '?=');
        }

        $this->setUseAbsoluteLinks(true);
        $text = $this->getProcessedTemplate($variables, true);
```

---

**[UPDATE]**

I've learned that when I enter a random, fake email for Forgot Password, and press submit, a confirmation appears, saying something like "If this email exists, then a new email was sent to that email!", but when I submit an email of a real existing customer, then it gives me the 500 error I've mentioned.

Still nothing - if anyone out there sees this, and you have a bit of time to help solve this perhaps, may Talos bless you!

---

**[SOLVED]**
I turns out this was a problem with transaction emails.
Cause by an extension, Mandrill, which is added to magento when I installed the MailChimp extension, called "MageMonkey - MailChimp Integration by ebizmarts"

Once I enabled Mandrill, in config, advanced, all transactions and transaction emails work perfectly fine!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that it's a .htaccess or server configuration problem.  Where is it hosted?  Do you have a .htaccess file in the root of the installation?

Comment: Hey there - yes, I do indeed have .htaccess file in root of the installation. It's just hosted on our own server running windows. Really the only problem I've had so far is the /customer/account/files working, such as /forgotpassowrdpost and /createpost